# Create an 'inverse' selection from a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a long and complex mysql query on a table with a lot of 'where FieldX like '%ABC%'' and a few 'where FieldX NOT like '%efg%'.  Without doing a bunch of search and replace to change like to not like and vice-versa, is there some simple query I can do to select the records that do not meet the large query parameters vs the ones that do as it is designed to do?

Simple example:

- I have TableA with a Field Called `Letter` with 26 records, one for each letter of the alphabet.

I then have a query that says:

```
Select * from TableA where `Letter` = 'A' or `Letter` = 'B' or `Letter` = 'C' or or `Letter` = 'D' or `Letter` = 'E' or `Letter` = 'F' or `Letter` not like 'G' or `Letter` not like 'H'
```

Now instead of doing a search and replace reverse/negate all of my 'where' conditions:

```
Select * from TableA where `Letter` != 'A' or `Letter` != 'B' or `Letter` != 'C' or or `Letter` != 'D' or `Letter` != 'E' or `Letter` != 'F' or `Letter` like 'G' or `Letter` like 'H'
```

I just want to use the existing query and get the same result. I thought there might be some way to add a select or other modifier to select all records BUT the ones in the original select:

```
Select * from TableA where `Letter` != (Select * from TableA where `Letter` != 'A' or `Letter` != 'B' or `Letter` != 'C' or or `Letter` != 'D' or `Letter` != 'E' or `Letter` != 'F' or `Letter` not like 'G' or `Letter` not like 'H')
```

Cleary I am not sure if my last example is working Mysql but that is my goal; encase my original query inside another that will end up returning all of the record NOT selected in the original query.

Comment: Can you add your query and table structure? Question is not so clear. What you expect to get?

Comment: Please edit your query and add a simplified version of your query, along with sample data and desired results.  It is a bit hard to figure out what you mean, unambiguously.  And, how long and complex could a query be on a single table?

Comment: Updated I hope that helps.

Comment: Queries, especially long and complex ones, are allowed to have line breaks in them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when inverting the comparisons, you also have to change `or` to `and`, otherwise you will get every record in the table. Everything is either not 'A' or not 'B'. :)

It should be:

```
Select * from TableA where `Letter` != 'A' and `Letter` != 'B' and ...
```

Back to the question, I think the easiest solution is to enclose the entire condition in parentheses and add a `not` operator:

```
Select * from TableA where not (`Letter` = 'A' or `Letter` = 'B' or ....)
```

Comment: Be careful if any `NULL` is involved, since `NULL = 'A'` is not true (but `null`), but `not NULL='A'` is also not true (but null). So NULL would come in none of both selects.

Comment: @flaschenpost You are right, of course. I left this out deliberately, since it didn't seem to apply to OP's situation, and to not make it more complex. But to be complete, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: I just wanted to add this information, since I was a bit confused (and it stole me some time) that the result set is in general not complete when you have all entries `where (condition)` and `where not (condition)`.

Answer (score 0):

GolezTrol's "`where not ()`" answer is correct as long as no `NULL` is involved. You could try if this works, but it is only for small tables, and gets slow on bigger tables.

```
select * from TableA as results 
where not exists 
( 
    select * from TableA as notResult where notResult.id = results.id and (Letter = 'A or Letter = 'B' ...) 
)
```